# Bootstrap - Navbar Collapse Border Break

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I changed navbar toggle's margin-top from 8 (default value) to 15. And because of this, at the collapsing, the border break.

```
.navbar-toggle { margin-top: 15px !important; }
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/StMGG.png

Comment: You need to post an actual working example of your code (HTML/CSS/JS). See [mcve] and [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Adjust your navbar-header. Your navbar-toggle is overflowing and it s covering the navbar-header border-bottom. Increase the height for the navbar-header and bring down any other element that may need to be centered now.

In order to not affect the height of the header at desktop view, make sure you are using this only when the navbar-toggle shows up which is only below 768px

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-toggle {
      margin-top: 15px;
  }

  .navbar-header {
      height: 58px; //change this as needed.
  }
}
```

Comment: @Asez if you mark it as an answer, others can benefit from it too :) Glad I helped

Comment: I needed a 60px navbar height (default = 50px). And instead of chaning the code, I used a custom bootstrap.

Comment: Did you try the code I gave you? with 60px instead of 58px?